# command prompt commands executing in windows application

Tags: c#, process, windows

i am trying in windows application i need to run another one application that's tetpdflib. that tetpdflib runs in command prompt only. when i drag and drop exe to the command prompt it will execute. for that i followed some coding

```
            Process tetmlProcess = new Process();
            tetmlProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            tetmlProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            tetmlProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            tetmlProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
            tetmlProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "cd C:\\Users\\sw_chn\\Documents\\PDFlib\\TET 5.0 32-bit\\bin\\tet.exe";

            tetmlProcess.Start();
```

but i cant get output.. and also i need to run following command prompt lines also

> cd tet.exe 
>   and tet -m filename

how to execute those commands in that process.

thats the full coding

```
    public static string inputfile = string.Empty;
    public static string outputfolder = string.Empty;

    private void btninputbrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog inputFileBrowser = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult result = inputFileBrowser.ShowDialog();
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            inputfile = inputFileBrowser.FileName;
            txtinput.Text = inputFileBrowser.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void btnoutputbrowse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderbrowsing = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = folderbrowsing.ShowDialog();
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            outputfolder = folderbrowsing.SelectedPath;
            txtoutput.Text = folderbrowsing.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void btnok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveInputFileToOutPutFolder();
    }

    private void MoveInputFileToOutPutFolder()
    {
        try
        {
            string[] splitinput = inputfile.Split('\\');
            outputfolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(outputfolder,splitinput.LastOrDefault());
            if (File.Exists(outputfolder))
            {
                File.Delete(outputfolder);
            }
            File.Copy(inputfile,outputfolder);
            TetmlApplicationRunning();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    private void TetmlApplicationRunning()
    {
        try
        {
            Process tetmlProcess = new Process();
            //tetmlProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            //tetmlProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            //tetmlProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            tetmlProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\\Users\\sw_chn\\Documents\\PDFlib\\TET 5.0 32-bit\\bin\\tet.exe";
            tetmlProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\\Users\\sw_chn\\Documents\\PDFlib\\TET 5.0 32-bit\\bin";
            tetmlProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "tetml -m wordplus" + inputfile;
            tetmlProcess.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: may be you need to set [WorkingDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: yes how to execute those 2 comments

Comment: should be `"tetml -m wordplus " + inputfile;` <-- note the space. Also note you wont need to split the string and get the last part to get the file name you can use [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: also you may need to specify the output `-o` option. Never worked with tet, just looked up the manual

Comment: i did't get final product
                tetmlProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                tetmlProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\sw_chn\Documents\PDFlib\TET 5.0 32-bit\bin";
                tetmlProcess.StartInfo.FileName = '"'+"C:\\Users\\sw_chn\\Documents\\PDFlib\\TET 5.0 32-bit\\bin\\tet.exe"+'"';
                tetmlProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "tet -m wordplus "+ System.IO.Path.GetFileName(outputfolder);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below. you won't need to run `cmd.exe` you can directly run `tet.ext`. Added comments in code.

```
Process tetmlProcess = new Process();
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// Instead of cmd.exe you run the tet.exe
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\\Users\\sw_chn\\Documents\\PDFlib\\TET 5.0 32-bit\\bin\\tet.exe";
//Set The working directory to C:\Users\sw_chn\Documents\PDFlib\TET 5.0 32-bit\bin\ if needed
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\\Users\\sw_chn\\Documents\\PDFlib\\TET 5.0 32-bit\\bin";
//Use the arguments required for tet.exe
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-m filename";

tetmlProcess.Start();
```

Note: This code is directly typed in here (have no access to visual studio now) so may contain syntax errors. Treat this only as guideline.

Comment: but i did't get exact output when i run that tool i get .tetml file with text coversion.but when i run throught vs just i got only txt file with out any text i will post full coding

Comment: Process tetmlProcess = new Process();                   tetmlProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\sw_chn\Documents\PDFlib\TET 5.0 32-bit\bin";
                
                tetmlProcess.StartInfo.FileName = '"'+"tet.exe"+'"';
                tetmlProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"tet -m wordplus D:\DailyWork\March\JOURNAL-ISSUE_6_3924-3930.pdf";
                tetmlProcess.Start();
what is the error on that?

Comment: you should use `.FileName = "tet.exe"`  and do you need tet as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

try the following snippet:

```
        var proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        string yourCommand;
        yourCommand = "calc.exe";
        proc.UseShellExecute = true;
        proc.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
        proc.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
        proc.Arguments = "/c " + yourCommand;
        proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        Process.Start(proc);
```

I run calculator; you can run your program as tet.exe and you must set the other parameters such as WorkingDirectory and FileName based on your .exe file.
This line of code 
`proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;`
 displays the cmd.exe window. If you are gonna not to display that, change the mentioned line of code to `proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;`
 I hope that work out!

Answer (score 0):

I owuld not try to simulate the command prompt, but execute the application directly. I assume that for this application output is sent to the console. You can redirect this output, but it is not possible to combine this with shell execute. I use the full path name to the application, which I set in the "Options" class and is stored in the registry. An example:

```
    static public String CompileScript(String InputFile, String OutputFile)
        {
        Process Compiler = new Process();
        String Result = String.Empty;
        try
            {
            Compiler.StartInfo.FileName = CLuaCreatorOptions.TrainSimulatorDirectory + "\\luac.exe";
            Compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v -o " + OutputFile + " " + InputFile;
            Compiler.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Compiler.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            Compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            Compiler.Start();
            Result = Compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + "\n" + Compiler.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            Compiler.WaitForExit();
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
            return "Error compiling script " + e.Message + "\r\n" + Result;
            }
        return Result;
        }
```

This example runs the LUA compiler and returns all error messages (async) to a string "Result". I show this sting in a multiline textbox in the forms application tha calls this compiler.

These three lines do the trick for you to redirect the output.

```
        Compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

To actually obtain the information, you need to run the application and pick up the output. You need to wait till the application exits to get complete results, the last three lines do that for you:

```
        Compiler.Start();
        Result = Compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + "\n" + Compiler.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        Compiler.WaitForExit();
```

Finally, you probably want to suppress the command window to be visible. This code will do that for you:

```
        Compiler.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Compiler.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```